# On an algebraic proof of base change theorem for Du Bois singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to S$ be any proper flat morphism between varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. The following property is well-known. (For instance, Theorem 2.63 in Kollár's "Families of varieties of general type".)

> **Theorem.** Suppose for any closed point $s\in S$, $X_s:=f^{-1}(\{s\})$ is Du Bois. Then $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is locally free and compatible with base change over $S$.

I tried to find the proof and all proofs about the theorem use singular cohomology theory that for Du Bois $Y$, $H^i(Y^{\mathrm{an}},\mathbb{C}_Y)\to H^i(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a surjection. I believe that there is an algebraic proof of the theorem. Is there a reference to my question?

Comment: Sandor Kovacs has an article where he proves results "of this kind" in positive characteristic as well.  That would be a good place to start.